# Integrating Hazelcast with a web application running on tomcat with MongoDB as backend

Tags: mongodb, tomcat, tomcat8, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to integrate Hazelcast with a web application running on a tomcat server. The backend is MongoDB. So far I have managed to integrate MongoDB with Hazelcast how do I integrate it with tomcat so that changes made to the DB through the UI can be seen in the IMaps used when i do a get call.

Comment: [hazelcast-integration/manager-based-session-replication](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/manager-based-session-replication) - is this what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every `get` call will load from DB, only those keys that are not present in Hazelcast cluster will be loaded from the DB.

As for integrating with a web server, not sure what you meant there because the code that loads from DB runs on Hazelcast server. An application, whether it is a simple `public static void main(...)` or a web app running in a container or a web server, is a client to Hazelcast server - means, you will be required to use client proxies to connect to servers.

Comment: `Not every get call will load from DB, only those keys that are not present in Hazelcast cluster will be loaded from the DB.` what about when we make some changes to that entry in DB will it get reflected in the IMap get call on that key.

Comment: `As for integrating ... servers.` The web application is deployed on a tomcat when I make a change in the database through the web application UI will I see the change reflected in the IMap when I do a fresh get call using the key for the modified entry.

Comment: `"a web app ... servers"`. How do I do this any leads on this part

Comment: If the key is already present in Hazelcast then it will not be loaded from DB regardless of the state of DB. If you want to reflect changes from DB into Hazelcast then you need Hazelcast Striim Hot Cache: https://hazelcast.com/products/solutions/hazelcast-striim-hot-cache/

Comment: See link for details on Client-Server deployments: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.1/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-clients

Comment: hazelcast striim cache seems to be a licensed software solution. do you know of any open source ones that are just as good.

Comment: There ain’t any.